# How to compare two LaTeX math strings for equality

Tags: math-mode, equations

I am creating educational application where users can answer using LaTeX and met situation where string equality doesn't work for some situations, though user answered right in meaning of result.

For example the right answer is `\frac{e+1}{4}` and usr answered `\frac{1+e}{4}` which is also right answer in meaning, so how we can compare these two LaTeX strings for meaning equality?

Comment: So it should also detect things like `(1+e)\cdot 4^{-1}` or if the user is creative `(\frac{4}{1+e})^{-1}`?

Comment: Or `0.25(e+1)`, or `\frac{e+4-3}{4}`? The point is that it is rather difficult to check all mathematical equivalences - however if you want to restrict it to a certain set of simple cases then you might be able to do it. A possible approach is to substitute all strings that match the regular expression `([a-z0-9])\+([a-z0-9])` with an expression created by sorting the list of elements.

Comment: @TeXnician Preferrably, but not necessarily :)

Comment: How about using `pythontex` and `sympy` checking for truth?

Comment: @Skillmon I think that can work, can you please, show some example or documentation part regarding to this

Comment: @ArenHovsepyan the problematic part would be parsing the LaTeX syntax into `sympy` syntax. I'll have to try some things but can't guarantee to produce anything working. Which functions do you need to be covered? `\frac` and others? How about `\exp`, `\cos`, `\sin` ... Is the argument to trigonometric functions always in rad or in degree?

Comment: Christian Lawson-Perfect has written about this sort of thing before: see https://www.checkmyworking.com/2014/06/pattern-matching-syntax-trees/ . He writes e-assessment software that has to grapple with this sort of thing all the time!

Comment: The only thing I would add to the post from @DavidR is WeBWorK which I couldn't see mentioned in the linked post

Answer (score 4):

You could use the Sympy library for Python which has an [experimental LaTeX parser](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html#experimental-mathrm-latex-parsing).  To compare the representations for equality you have to use the `.equals()` function because `==` performs a raw object comparison and will return true only if the two objects are equal.

```python
>>> from sympy.parsing.latex import parse_latex
>>> expr1 = parse_latex(r"\frac{e+1}{4}")
>>> expr2 = parse_latex(r"\frac{1+e}{4}")
>>> expr1.equals(expr2)
True
>>> expr3 = parse_latex(r"\frac{e+4-3}{4}")
>>> expr1.equals(expr3)
True
>>> expr4 = parse_latex(r"0.25(e+1)")
>>> expr1.equals(expr4)
True
>>> expr5 = parse_latex(r"(1+e)\cdot 4^{-1}")
>>> expr1.equals(expr5)
True
>>> expr6 = parse_latex(r"(\frac{4}{1+e})^{-1}")
>>> expr1.equals(expr6)
True
```